# ¿Cómo hago que el position fixed no se salga de su contenedor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, script, template

Uitlicé este script para hacer un timeline vertical, pero el problema es que como la sección del menú del timeline tiene un position:fixed, se ajusta a la ventana en vez de al contenedor padre, y entonces queda por encima de la portada de la página (ya que la timeline y el contenido de la misma está en un contenedor que aparece después de la portada de la página).
¿Alguna ayuda sobre cómo puedo corregir esto para que la timeline no se salga del lugar?

Este es el código en codepen: https://codepen.io/lebedevdesigns/pen/KQZYjo

Comment: `fixed` siempre va ajustado relativo a la ventana, `absolute` va ajustado al primer ancestro  `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` o ventana.

Comment: Hola Matìas Fernandez, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te sugiero revisar [ask]. Lo mas importante es que agregues que has intentado y en que estás fallando dentro de la respuesta, si el código se puede ejecutar en navegador puedes utilizar un [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet) y así si el link deja de funcionar pueda ser de utilidad para los usuario en el futuro

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar un elemento `fixed` en relación con un elemento `parent`, lo que necesitas es `position:absolute` en el elemento secundario y cualquier modo de posición que no sea el predeterminado o estático en su elemento primario.

Por ejemplo:

```
#padre { position:relative; }
#hijo { position:absolute; left:50px; top:20px; }
```

Esto colocará el elemento `hijo` 50 píxeles a la izquierda y 20 píxeles abajo de la posición del `padre`.

Para colocar un elemento `fixed` en relación con la ventana, lo que necesitas es `position:fixed`, y puedes usar `top:`, `left:`, `right:` y `bottom:` para posicionar dentro de la ventana.

Por ejemplo:

```
#cuadro { position:fixed; bottom:40px; right:40px; }
```

Esto posicionará `#cuadro` fijo en relación con la ventana del navegador web, 40 píxeles desde el borde inferior y 40 píxeles desde el borde derecho.

P.D. Cambiando a `step: 42` en `const TIMELINE_VALUES` se aprecia mejor el 'codepen'.